# Duplicated ORDER BY Data and Conditions In Query Every Time Called

Tags: jooq

I've noticed this before and long ago stopped having my `Condition`s be private static finals, but I'm scratching my head on this one because it's a bit more problematic, especially if I'm debugging a query.  Here's the example (and I've seen this before in 3.3.x, although I'm currently at 3.7.3):

```
        final SelectJoinStep<Record13<String, String, String, String, String, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, String, BigDecimal, String, String, Byte>> query = getSelect()
                .from(getFrom(coConditions,
                        ConditionUtils.buildCondition(cortConditions, removeCortBySpeciality),
                        ConditionUtils.buildCondition(cosConditions, removeCosBySensitivity), tuConditions,
                        uaConditions, enableBlackMajik));
        final SortField<?>[] orders = new SortField[] {DSL.inline(Integer.valueOf(2)).asc(),
                DSL.inline(Integer.valueOf(1)).asc(), DSL.inline(Integer.valueOf(6)).asc()};

        if (cosConditions.isPresent()) {
            User.logger.error(builder.renderInlined(query.where(cosConditions.get()).orderBy(orders)));
            return query.where(cosConditions.get()).orderBy(orders);
        }

        User.logger.error(builder.renderInlined(query.orderBy(orders)));
        return query.orderBy(orders);
```

Here's the SQL snippet from the logger call just showing the `ORDER BY`:

```
order by 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc
```

And here's the SQL snippet of the `ORDER BY` that is sent to the SQL server:

```
order by 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc, 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc
```

Now, to further show the fun, here's another code snippet written just to demonstrate the problem:

```
        User.logger.error(builder.renderInlined(query.orderBy(orders)));
        User.logger.error(builder.renderInlined(query.orderBy(orders)));
        User.logger.error(builder.renderInlined(query.orderBy(orders)));
        return query.orderBy(orders);
```

First logger call:

```
order by 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc
```

Second logger call:

```
order by 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc, 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc
```

Third logger call:

```
order by 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc, 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc, 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc
```

What the DB sees:

```
order by 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc, 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc, 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc, 
  2 asc, 
  1 asc, 
  6 asc
```

Now, again, I actually have noticed this kind of behaviour before with my `Condition`s, where each time I call a `Condition` it is replicated to the point where I build my conditions and only reference them once (static ones made for some fun).  Does anyone know why I'm seeing this behaviour (and see like behaviour with Conditions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an API design flaw in jOOQ that jOOQ has been carrying around for quite a while and will be fixed with jOOQ 4.0 only ([#2198](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2198)).

In general, you cannot safely assume that the DSL API is immutable (although it should be). So, your consecutive calls to `orderBy()` will actually each add the `ORDER BY` column set, but you print only the first one, so you don't see that.

The current behaviour is explained here (scroll to "mutability"):

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/dsl-and-non-dsl

Comment: I'm just glad to find that this whole time I wasn't crazy!  I would query my SQL server to see the times things are running and scratch my head going, "Wait... I don't remember doubling that up".